# Oracle dba_data_files table doesn't exist

Tags: oracle, ora-00942, data-files

I've been trying to access the [dba_data_files table](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_3083.htm) to see whether the `autoextend` is turned on for my data files.  However, even though I'm using Oracle 10g, this table seems to not exist:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options

SQL> select * from dba_data_files;
select * from dba_data_files
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Is there some other way to check and even change whether a data file for a particular tablespace has the autoextend option turned on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should make sure you're connecting with an account that has privileges to see this view - try the SYSTEM account if you have that password, otherwise have your DBA grant the SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE to the account you are using.

Comment: Thanks - it never occurred to me that it would say "table or view does not exist" if it did actually exist and I merely didn't have permission to view it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this through the oracle enterprise manager under Administration